# Remove series of characters in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Somewhat of a beginner in pandas.

I am trying to clean data in a specific column by removing a series of characters.

Currently the data looks like this:

```
**Column A**

 (F) Red Apples

 (F) Oranges 

 Purple (F)Grapes

 (F) Fried Apples
```

I need to remove the (F)

I used … `df[‘Column A’]=df[‘Column A’].str.replace(‘[(F)]’,’ ‘)`

This successfully removed the (F) but it also removed the other F letters (for example Fried Apples = ied Apples) How can I only remove the “series” of characters.

Comment: `df[‘Column A’].str.replace(‘\(F\)’,’ ‘)` is the regex expression to catch those `(F)`'s

Comment: Pass `regex=False`

Comment: To expand on why, the parentheses are being read as regular expression special characters due to `Series.str.replace()` using regex by default. You either need to escape them with backslashes or tell pandas not to use regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
df['Column A'].str.replace('\(F\)','')
```

```
0       Red Apples
1          Oranges
2    Purple Grapes
3     Fried Apples
Name: Column A, dtype: object
```

OR

```
df['Column A'].str.replace('(F)','', regex=False)
```

Comment: df[‘Column A’].str.replace(‘\(F\)’, ‘’) did the trick. Thanks for the speedy answers!

Comment: Glad to help, feel free to mark the answer if it helped solve your question.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```py
data={'Column A':["(F) Red Apples","(F) Oranges ","Purple (F)Grapes","(F) Fried Apples"]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)

df['Column A']=df['Column A'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('(F)', ''))
```

```
0    Red Apples

1    Oranges 

2    Purple Grapes

3    Fried Apples
```